# ubuntu not shown as boot option when installed with windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-8

My laptop came pre installed with windows 7 and currently has windows 8.1 after upgradation. I installed Ubuntu on it from a usb drive by selecting a partition(not the side by side windows option). Installation completed successfully.  But it does not give an option to boot to linux. It boots directly to windows. I tried boot repair. But still the issue persists. Some forums suggested the issue may be due to secure boot but it is not there in my laptop.

What could be the issue?How can I solve this?

If nothing else works, is there any way by which I can uninstall the ubuntu and try re installing it from scratch?

The boot-repair details are at http://paste.ubuntu.com/7868025/

Comment: Usually you need to select your is from your bios

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following:

1. Plug in the USB drive containing your Ubuntu installer.
2. Change the boot order so that it boots from USB.
3. Boot to the Ubuntu USB drive.
4. Select "Try Ubuntu without installing".
5. Open a terminal window by pressing "CTRL+ALT+T".
6. Run the following commands (in order) to install Boot-Repair:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
   ```
7. Open Boot-Repair from the Dash.
8. Click the "Recommended repair" button.
9. Reboot without installing Ubuntu.
10. Select your operating system from the list using the arrow keys on your keyboard.

The steps above should install GRUB2, the boot loader used by Ubuntu, to your Master Boot Record (MBR). Once this is done, you will reboot your system and should be able to select either Ubuntu or Windows from the GRUB2 list using the arrow keys on your keyboard.

The above steps are a concise version of the steps found at the [Ubuntu Boot-Repair Community Help Wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I already tried these steps of boot-repair .It didnt solve this issue. I have added the link to the boot repair paste bin link :(

Comment: The problem is usually with the bios, not grub